# Export SQL Server geography to kml with altitude

Tags: sql-server, kml, sqlgeography

I need to export a bunch of geography objects to kml, and with that include a 3rd element, altitude. Luckily it can be hard coded as 0.

[This tutorial](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#polygons) implies the coordinates need to be in the format of lat,long,alt

```
<coordinates>
    -77.05788457660967,38.87253259892824,100 
    -77.05465973756702,38.87291016281703,100 
    -77.05315536854791,38.87053267794386,100 
    -77.05552622493516,38.868757801256,100 
    -77.05844056290393,38.86996206506943,100 
    -77.05788457660967,38.87253259892824,100
</coordinates>
```

How do I extract the coordinate list from my geography objects?

Is it possible to include injecting the altitude?

Comment: "format of lat,long,alt" is not correct, that tutorial/reference says: `<coordinates>(required)
floating point values for **longitude, latitude, and altitude**. The altitude component is optional. Do not include spaces within a tuple.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part I was really looking for was .Lat and .Long.  They only work on POINT's, not POLYGON's, so you have to break that down the **@input** into points

This returns a varchar(MAX) string like long,lat,alt**cr/lf**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[uf_ConvertGeographyToCoordinates]
(
    @input geography
)
RETURNS nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @result nvarchar(max) = '' -- Out needs to be not null
    DECLARE @long nvarchar(25)
    DECLARE @lat nvarchar(25)
    DECLARE @alt nvarchar(25)
    DECLARE @altitude nvarchar(1) = '0'
    DECLARE @i int = 1 
    DECLARE @crlf nvarchar(2) = char(13) + char(10)


    WHILE @i <@input.STNumPoints() 
    BEGIN 

        SET @long = ISNULL(LTRIM(STR(@input.STPointN(@i).Long, 25, 8)), 'null_long') 
    
        SET @lat = ISNULL(LTRIM(STR(@input.STPointN(@i).Lat, 25, 8)), 'null_lat') 
    
        SET @alt = ISNULL(@altitude, 'null_alt')

        SET @result = @result + @long + ',' + @lat + ',' + @alt + @crlf

        SET @i = @i + 1; 
    END 

    return @result
END
GO
```